# ¿Como mover de lugar los HTML5 export buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Tengo un detalle con los botones **export** de los `datatables`, lo que pasa que es que al generar nuevamente el `datatable` los botones me descompone el `header` de la tabla.

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de moverlos de lugar al generarlos junto con la tabla o alguna manera para que no me esconda el `header` de la tabla

```js
window.dataTable = jQuery('#dyntable').DataTable({
         dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]
    });
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dyntable">
         <colgroup>
            <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 5%" />
            <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 25%" />
            <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 10%" />
            <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 20%" />
            <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 15%" />
            <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 25%" />
         </colgroup>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th style="background:#66898E; color: #fff;" class="head0 nosort center">Id</th>
               <th style="background:#66898E; color: #fff;" class="center">Nombre</th>
               <th style="background:#66898E; color: #fff;" class="center">Puesto</th>
               <th style="background:#66898E; color: #fff;" class="left">Correo</th>
               <th style="background:#66898E; color: #fff;" class="center">Telefono</th>
               <th style="background:#66898E; color: #fff;" class="center">Empresa</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody id="tbody1">
            
         </tbody>
      </table>
```

Esta es la tabla antes de generarla con los botones para exportar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta imagen ya es cuando se genera la tabla ya con datos y los botones y donde se aprecia que el `header` de la tabla desaparece con los botones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes moverlos usando los parametros de configuración de los botones de la siguiente manera:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "ajax": 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu',
        "order": [],
        "dom": 'Bfrtip',        
        "buttons": {
           "dom": {
              "button": {
                "tag": "button",
                "className": "waves-effect waves-light btn mrm"
              }
           },
           "buttons": [ 'copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5', 'csvHtml5', 'pdfHtml5' ]   
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.mrm {
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jszip-2.5.0,pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-html5-1.0.3/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jszip-2.5.0,pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-html5-1.0.3/datatables.min.js"></script>


<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Usando [buttons.dom.button](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.dom.button) para darle clases y seleccionar el elemento al que quieras editar.